# 2 Domains, Same Content, Different Titles?

Tags: posts, title, google-search, search-engines

Hi just wondering if this is at all possible for example:

You can access through A.com or B.com but the titles of the page change accordingly, so if you were on home on A.com the title and google results would show

A.com | Home

And the same could be said for B.com

Is it possible to do this or would it be a case of cloning the content from A.com and moving it to B.com?

Comment: if it is different title, it is not same content. You probably need to clrify which title you are talking about

Comment: @MarkKaplun exact same pages, exact same products, exact same descriptions, I believe this is actually the same content.

Comment: please give more explanations about what you want to do

Comment: @mmm I want everything on the two sites to be the exact same except the title when viewing the pages and in search results to show the domain name of the domain it is being viewed from

Comment: I'm with @MarkKaplun here.    To say it the other way:  If the content is the same, how could the title be the same?